# How to switch Keycloak’s development mode to production mode

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I have added my docker compose file here for reference

```
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    command:
      [
        "start-dev",
        "--http-port=8081",
        "--http-relative-path=/auth"
      ]
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin1234
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

I've included a Docker Compose file on this page for your reference. I'm having trouble running Keycloak in production mode. Can you assist me with this?

I want to tell you one more thing that when I make changes in the docker compose file like 'start' command or volume then keycloak container starts and then becomes exits after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the solution here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers

As you can see you have to create an image with your configuration:

Dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=postgres

# Access data
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin1234

#you need an hostname in production mode! set it right or you will have infinite Console loading.
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost

#relative path
ENV KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth

#http port
ENV KC_HTTP_PORT= 8081

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=postgres
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=postgres

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

build this Docker file:

```
docker build . -t mykeycloak
```

After that you can just run the image in docker-compose:

```
keycloak:
    image: mykeycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    command:
      [
        "start-dev",
        "--optimized",
      ]
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```